# Insert static code block into a php "while loop" after "N" loops.

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a php while loop, but I want to insert a "static" code block into it after the third item in the loop and then continue the loop after the static content. Can someone help me update my code to accomplish the "desired outcome" below?

**My Code**

```
$x = 0;
    while($x <= 5) {
        $contentItems = $relatedArray[$rand_keys[$x]];
            $contentItems = explode('|', $contentItems);
            echo '
                <p><a href="'.$contentItems[3].'"><img class="faux" src="'.$contentItems[4].'"></a></p>
                ';
        $x++;
    }
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
Loop Content
Loop Content
Loop Content
**STATIC CONTENT**
Loop Content
Loop Content
Loop Content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `if` conditional inside of your `while` loop that checks against the index:

```
$x = 0;
while($x <= 5) {

    // Will only trigger halfway through the loop
    if ($x == 3) {
        echo '**STATIC CONTENT**';
    }

    $contentItems = $relatedArray[$rand_keys[$x]];
    $contentItems = explode('|', $contentItems);
    echo '<p><a href="'.$contentItems[3].'"><img class="faux" src="'.$contentItems[4].'"></a></p>';

    $x++;
}
```

Note that this will **still output** the original item at this position. If you want to **replace** it instead, you'll want to wrap everything related to `$contentItems` inside of an `else` conditional :)